# Ejecutar proceso batch automáticamente

Tags: java, xml, batch, proceso

he creado un proceso batch completo y funcional, el cual ejecuto corriendo manualmente un Launcher.java que tiene un metodo main y ejecuta el job que he definido (este job lo he definido en un xml y se lo paso como argumentos a mi main), eso funciona perfecto así, ahora busco llevarlo a producción y para eso necesito configurar que ese proceso se ejecute todos los días a la una de la mañana de España, como puedo hacer eso?
Este es mi Launcher (si le hago clic derecho run as-> Application java, funciona perfecto pero como se hace para que un batch se ejecute solo como lo necesito?)

```
 public final class Launcher {

private static final String LOG_DECORATOR = "****************************************.";
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger("batch");
private static final Long MIL = 1000L;

private Launcher(){
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    LOG.info(LOG_DECORATOR);
    LOG.info(" INICIO DEL PROCESO ");
    LOG.info(LOG_DECORATOR);

    LOG.info("Cargando datos de configuracion");

    final ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(args[0]);

    final PropertyFacade property = applicationContext.getBean(PropertyFacade.class);
    Assert.notNull(property, "Datos de configuracion no cargados correctamente");
    final String entorno = property.property("entorno");
    LOG.info("Entorno: ".concat(entorno));
    final JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) applicationContext.getBean("jobLauncher");
    final Job job = (Job) applicationContext.getBean("job");
    long tiempoComenzar;
    long tiempoTerminar;
    tiempoComenzar = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        final JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
        LOG.info("Job Status : " + execution.getStatus());
        LOG.info("Job completed");
    } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException e) {
        LOG.info("Error Launcher: ".concat(e.toString()));
        LOG.error("Exception Launcher",e);
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
        LOG.info("Error Launcher: ".concat(e.toString()));
        LOG.error("Exception Launcher",e);
    } catch(JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException e){
        LOG.info("Error Launcher: ".concat(e.toString()));
        LOG.error("Exception Launcher",e);
    } catch(JobParametersInvalidException e){
        LOG.info("Error Launcher: ".concat(e.toString()));
        LOG.error("Exception Launcher",e);
    } catch(JobRestartException e){
        LOG.info("Error Launcher: ".concat(e.toString()));
        LOG.error("Exception Launcher",e);
    }finally {
        ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) applicationContext).close();
        tiempoTerminar = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final long tiempoDedicado = (tiempoTerminar - tiempoComenzar) / MIL;
        LOG.info(
                "Fin. Tiempo dedicado a la consulta: ".concat(String.valueOf(tiempoDedicado)).concat(" segundos."));
        LOG.info(LOG_DECORATOR);
        LOG.info(" FIN DEL PROCESO ");
        LOG.info(LOG_DECORATOR);
    }

}
```

}

Este es el Job

[image: click me]

Agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias alternativas:

**- Sistema**

En el caso de windows puede usar el programador de tareas para que ejecute el jar que genera el app que hizo, o en el caso de linux puede usar crontab

**- Aplicacion**

Puede implementar el uso de Quartz

- link de ejemplo http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-01.html